# how can I make the browser treat css in a file with same precedence as inline css?

Tags: html, css

when I put css in `<style></style>` tags directly in the HTML it trumps any css in a file loaded with:

```
<link href="foo1.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But I don't want any inline styles in the html.  So I moved the css to a file named foo2.css and have:

```
<link href="foo1.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="foo2.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I also tried:

```
<link href="foo2.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="foo1.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

changing the order.  But it doesn't seem to work.  How can I tell the browser to treat foo2.css just like it would inline style?

Comment: If you want to override a css style, you give the overriding value `!important`. If you have two values and none (or both) are overriding, you need to rethink your methodology.

Comment: i was always told don't use important: http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/

Comment: Can't you simply edit foo1.css to incorporate the inline styles? I too feel the use of `!important` is something to avoid.

Comment: `!important` can certainly be abused (and it generally is), but it is still a critical component of css. If you have css that is adversely impacting elements that is isn't suppose to, than re-organize the structure of your css classes so the correct elements get only the style they require.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't use `!important`

You will regret it later.  Instead, use stronger selectors.

```css
.weakSelector { }
div.strongerSelector { }
#strongSelector { }
div#superStrongSelector { }
html > body > div.wrapper > div.content > section > article > p > a:link#superUltraMegaStrongSelector { }
```

If you use identical selectors, the stronger selector is the one that appears later in the document.

Use developer tools (hint: hit <kbd>F12</kbd> in any browser) to see what selector is winning, and make your selector stronger.

The "Trace Styles" tab in IE's dev tools is particularly useful for identifying the stronger selector:

[image: IE Dev Tools]

Chrome's dev tools will also show you where styles come from, but you sometimes have to scroll around and hunt for it.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

And, of course, there's firebug (`HTML > Style > Show applied styles`) but no more screenshots... you get the idea. ;-)

Comment: What about cases such as jQueryUI where you may need to override css? `!important` is much nicer than editing the source css file. `!important` is just a tool that can be abused or used correctly to help comment explicit behavior.

Comment: @BradM - jQueryUI is unobtrusive.  It uses linked stylesheets and applies classes rather than setting style attribute values.  It is *intended* that you define your own styles when using jQueryUI. They provide a base stylesheet and let you customize it, or let you create a custom theme.

Comment: Between an instruction with `!important` and a selector made of an id, didn't count the classes and pseudos and 8 elements, you're still choosing the latter, really? oO The slightest change to your HTML code and bam, doesn't match anymore! I'd add a specific class (yay, a selector with only one or two classes) or an `!important` or would revise my strategy before I'd ever think about writing down a selector with so much parts...

Comment: @BradM - One more thing.  (Sorry, I can't help myself)  I just completely disagree with this: *`!important` is much nicer than editing the source css file.*  That's exactly opposite to the point! Editing the source css file to make the selectors stronger is *much* nicer than using `!important`.

Comment: @FelipeAls - Right, I would never actually use that selector.  I was just using it as illustration to make the point.  Really, I'd just duplicate the stronger selector and include it later in the document. Or, as you suggest, add a class to my HTML and use that to strengthen the selector.

Comment: @gilly3 It is valid to look at it through a semantic / logical point of view. Making something `!important` may infer that that selector can be safely removed with an underlying "fallback" selector to handle the styling. Finding usefulness in that logic is up to the developer / scenario.

Answer (score 2):

you put !important before the semicolon in your CSS document

```
div {
    width:100px !important;
}
```

This will override all CSS including inline.

Answer (score 1):

`!important` should only be used as a last resort.  The real goal should be to increase the specificity of the foo2.css styles because that's how the browser decides which style to use.

Without seeing your code it's impossible to say for sure, but you could likely just add a prefix before every style in foo2.css with a `.container` class if you have one or if there isn't a consistent container then you could prefix all styles with `body` so they're more specific than the foo1.css styles, forcing them to be used.

Using !important or a generic prefix isn't the best way to build a new site but if that's the easiest way to remove inline styles the tradeoff is worth it for the huge maintainability improvement while allowing the browser to cache your styles.

Answer (score 0):

If your inlined styles are like:

```
<section style="text-align: left; width: 50%; float: right;">
    blah
</section>
```

I'd add generic classes in the HTML code:

```
<section style="txtleft w50 right">
    blah
</section>
```

and matching CSS helper rules:

```
.txtleft {
    text-align: left !important;
}

.w50 {
    width: 50%;
}
.w200p {
    width: 200px;
}

.right {
    float: right !important;
}
```

No more strict separation of structure and style but it's still way better than inline styles and classes are self-explaining (you see both structure and main styles by reading your HTML code, updating styles is as simple as removing/adding classes in it).
I add `!important` on `.txtleft` and `.right` because the intent is pretty clear: if I add one of these classes, I DO want the relevant instruction to be applied else I wouldn't add it, simple as that. Without `!important`, any selector more specific than a class (or as specific as a class but written after these rules) would be applied instead of these ones.
`.w50` is a different case: by experience, you may need to override width for lesser versions of IE or in `@media` rules for Responsive Web Design so adding `!important` would force you into adding it everywhere and you'd back into adding more and more specificity... Meh.